# Suppress Autolayout Warnings

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I have 3 image views that I have placed in the nib. They need to start at a different y value based on portrait or landscape. Additionally, they will move to the bottom of the screen based on a button click. At that point, I remove the top constraint and add a bottom constraint.

Due to the complexity of this, I decided to handle those particular constraints in the code. However, I still get a warning that the y position for those image views is ambiguous.

Is there any way for me to tell Xcode not to worry, that I have set the constraints in code? The only solution I can think of is to create a constraint in the nib and delete it on view did load but that seems hacky.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add constraints that are removed at build time. This tells interface builder that you're going to handle it in code. Working on capturing a screen shot.

[image: Screen shot of setting when constraint is selected]